# Получение кода веб страницы

Tags: php, html, mysql

Я хочу на своем сайте реализовать редактор статических и уже готовых страниц. План следующий: 
html код этой страницы хранится в БД;
я захожу на страницу и при помощи функций document.body.contentEditable = true; и document.designMode = 'on'; могу редактировать текст на самой странице и понятное дело, что после ее перезагрузки текст меняется обратно;
я пытаюсь получить html код страницы уже после ее редактирования (если после редактирования нажать "просмотреть код", без перезагрузки страницы, то мои изменения остаются на месте) и заменить код этой страницы в БД на отредактированный код;
В итоге проблема - не могу получить код страницы уже после редактирования. cURL и file_get_contents выдают мне код, который был до редактирования.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть.
Возможно я изобретаю велосипед, но какого то еще способа придумать не могу. Мне нужен вариант как можно исправлять ошибки в тексте после создания этой страницы. Нужно редактировать только слова.

Comment: добавьте кнопку сохранить, возьмите `document.body.innerHTML` и отправьте на сайт через тот же post

Comment: @splash58 не очень понял как это реализовать. По кнопке выполнить функцию document.body.innerHTML и результат отправить на сервер?

Comment: это не функция, это собственно, текст страницы `let body = document.body.innerHTML`

Comment: @splash58 буду пытаться разобраться. Спасибо

Comment: @splash58 я пишу <script>let innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;</script> <input type="button" onclick='document.location.href="../controller/test.php?innerHTML=" + innerHTML' value="press"> и по ссылке улетает пустая строка. Почему так может быть?

Comment: я написал в ответе, как это мне видится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let edit = document.querySelector('.edit')
let save = document.querySelector('.save')
let article = document.querySelector('.article')

edit.onclick = function() {
  edit.style.display = 'none';
  save.style.display = 'block';
  article.contentEditable = true; 
  }
save.onclick = function() {
  edit.style.display = 'block'
  save.style.display='none';
  article.contentEditable = false; 
  $.post( "ContrlerToSave.php", { text: article.innerHTML, url: window.location.href } );
  }
```

```css
.save { display:none}
```

```html
<button class='edit'>edit</button>
<button class='save'>save</button>
<div class='article'>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```